# junk after document element: line 13, column 2

Tags: python, xml, django, xml-parsing, django-views

while parsing xml file,i am getting the following traceback

```
ParseError at /addxml/
junk after document element: line 13, column 2
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/addxml/
Django Version: 1.3.7
Exception Type: ParseError
Exception Value:    
junk after document element: line 13, column 2
Exception Location: /root/Samples/DemoApp/DemoApp/views.py in addxml, line 98
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
```

This is my code

```
if request.POST:
        path = "{0}/app_name/filename.xml".format(settings.PROJECT_ROOT)
        xmlDoc = open(path, 'r')
        xmlDocData = xmlDoc.read()
        xmlDocTree = etree.XML(xmlDocData)
```

below line is giving the error

```
xmlDocTree = etree.XML(xmlDocData)



<book>
    <book_id>101</book_id>
    <book_name>Python</book_name>
    <publisher_name>Maxwell</publisher_name>
    <author_id>1002</author_id>
    <first_name>John</first_name>
    <last_name>Dezosa</last_name>
    <email>john@gmail.com</email>
    <age>34</age>
  </book>
  <book>
    <book_id>102</book_id>
    <book_name>Django</book_name>
    <publisher_name>Technical</publisher_name>
    <author_id>1003</author_id>
    <first_name>Josep</first_name>
    <last_name>Raj</last_name>
    <email>joseph@gmail.com</email>
    <age>29</age>
  </book>
```

Thanks

Comment: And what is your XML data?

Comment: XML data updated in the question

Comment: That is not valid XML, there is not top-level element.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do not have a single root element.  Try adding a parent above each of your `book` elements.  Maybe `books`?

```
<books>
  <book> ... </book>
  <book> ... </book>
</books>
```

If that does not help try looking at line 13, col 2 like the error message suggests.

```
bad_line = xmlDocData.splitlines()[12]
```